# How to define an inner product?

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

Suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and let  $P$, an element of  $L(V)$, satisfy $P^2 = P$.

Show that you can define an inner product on $V$ so that $P$ is orthogonal projection to some subspace.

I know that an idempotent projection is the direct sum of the null space and the range but I don't know what to do next. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The nullspace tells the *direction* of the projection, and we want it to be orthogonal to the projected space (the range). 
So take any basis in both the nullspace ($e_1,\dots, e_k)$ and the range ($e_{k+1},\dots, e_n$),  and define
$$\big\langle \sum_i\alpha_ie_i,\ \sum_i\beta_ie_i\big\rangle \ :=\ \sum_i\alpha_i\beta_i$$
Verify that $P$ is indeed an orthogonal projection with respect to this inner product.

Comment: How do I show that <v,w> = conjugate <w,v> in this case?

Comment: You nowhere mentioned that you work over $\Bbb C$. In that case, the right hand side of the definition should rather be $\sum_i\bar{\alpha_i}\beta_i$.